# IDAPython NtCreateFile

Tags: binary-analysis, idapython, pe, idapro-sdk

Let's say I want to print the filenames on every call to [NtCreateFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile)
(With *%any%* exe loaded in IDA )

---

The first problem is to get the `ntdll!NtCreateFile` address
Tried to do it like this `get_name_ea_simple('ntdll_NtCreateFile')` but `"module 'ntdll' has no names"`

Although the call `get_name_ea_simple('kernel32_CreateFileW')` works just fine: `0x770d08d0`
*(if debugger paused on executable EP)*

And here is second problem - exec script commands after debugger loads all modules info.
If I do something like:

```
run_to(get_inf_attr(INF_MIN_EA)) # start the debugger and execute to the entry point
CreateFileW = get_name_ea_simple('kernel32_CreateFileW')
    if CreateFileW == BADADDR:
        warning('kernel32_CreateFileW is null')
        return
```

I'll get my warning.
So how to do it right?

---

*IDA 7.5*

**Added**

I found out that if we stop at the entry point and manually load symbols for `ntdll`, then the following command works `get_name_ea_simple('ZwCreateFile')`

Comment: ntddl   typo ? .....

Comment: Thx. Yes `'ntdll' has no names`